# Optimizing Nested For loops in C

Tags: c, loops, matrix, optimization

I am working on code where I have nested 'for loops' which is often used for calculation of matrix.

Below is example.

```
for( j = 0; j < col; j++ )
{
    for( i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
        {
             float temp_var = *(mat1 + ( i * Col) + j );
             for( k = 0; k < rows; k++ )
             {
                 if( k != i )
                 {
                     if( *(mat1 + ( k * col) + j ) == temp_var )
                     {
                         count++;
                     }
                 }
             }

         *(mat1 + ( i * col) + j ) = count;
    }
}
for( j = 0; j < rows; j++ )
{
    count = 0;
    for( i = 0; i < col; i++ )
    {
        float temp_var = *(mat1+ ( j * col) + i );
        for( k = 0; k< col; k++)
            {
                if( k != i)
                {
                    if( *(mat1 + ( j * col) + k ) == temp_var )
                    {
                        count = count + 2;
                    }
                }
            }

        *(mat1 + ( j * col) + i ) = count;
        }
    }
```

One way would be splitting them into different functions. But I would like to if I can optimize in more efficient manner and also to improve readability .

Comment: Splitting the loops into different functions will not help performance, if anything it will be worse if the compiler doesn’t inline them. If you are gonna optimze, optimize your algorithm first and code second.

Comment: Optimizing is a big topic, and if your first thought is splitting into functions, I guess you're starting from scratch. Start by deciding how fast you need your code to be, then measure it. If it's _fast enough_ - you're done! If not, you need to profile it.

Comment: For example, you can't have optimal layout for both row-major and column-major loops, so you must choose which one is more important. Here, the first loop will have worse memory access patterns than the second, but they can't _both_ be optimal.

Comment: You could optimize all square matrices by actually using a one-dimensional array and mess around with division (`/`) and modulo (`%`) to simulate rows and columns. At least it can save time during initialisation because you could usually do a single allocation. But well, don't optimize prematurely.

Comment: @Fredrik : Thank you for input. Splitting the loops was one thought but Understand your input

Comment: @Useless you're right, here column major will have high weight-age the row major

Comment: @Cheatah Thank you for suggestion, And as I understand during execution it will same issue

Comment: @Fredrik but unfortunately I have no option for algorithmic optimization as now

Comment: Sometimes it's better to optimize the compilation than the algorithms or the code, take a look at the assembly both with and without optimization.

**https://godbolt.org/z/_Wrp9N**

I extrapolated all the variables since none is declared in your code. Of course all the unused variables will be removed by the optimization, but it's a demonstration how optimization can be very beneficial.

Comment: @Useless Actually, the two loop can have an optimal layout if a transposition is done between the two parts (eventually with an out-of-place computation). The cost of a transposition is chip compare to the two parts as its complexity is `O(n^2)` compare to the `O(n^3)` of the two parts (this is especially true if the transposition is carefully optimized).

Answer (score 0):

Some minor ways in which you can make your code more readable and concise:

1. count += 2 (instead of count = count + 2)
2. As (mat1+ ( j * col) + i ) is reused multiple times, you can store it in a variable like

   `auto myVar = (mat1+ ( j * col) + i );` this would make you code more readable.

Bonus: Whenever you don't need indexes in for loop, for(auto x: arr) can be a wise option.